# How to stop a single database in an sql instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For example i have 15 database in my instance how can i stop only one of them?. I only know is how to stop an instance... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it Offline in SSMS.

Right click -> Task -> Take Offline

You can set database to Restricted User Mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET RESTRICTED_USER
```

but I'm not sure this works on SQL Server 2008

Comment: this will make to stop the single database?.

Comment: I tried it but I can't access it I need to access it.

Comment: then you should grant access to one user only

Comment: how to grant access for the user?.

Comment: using database Properties -> Permissions and grant access to only one account. you can force one user in Properties -> Options -> Restrict Access: SINGLE_USER or RESTRICTED_USER

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/sqlrestricteduser.aspx

Comment: sorry quite new in database like that. what should i right click the database that i want to have a grant or the instance?.

Comment: if it is in single user. all other user that have an access to the database can't connect?.

Comment: you must grant only one connection, try if this works with sql-2008: ALTER DATABASE database-name SET RESTRICTED_USER

Answer (score 1):

Stopping a database means making it unavailable for users. You should make database off-line. Right click on database and select Off-Line.

Comment: But i cant access it. I need to do something in that database.